# Share the same piece of data in multiple controllers and views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Lets say that we have a rails app which has a sidebar on every page that shows some data, like post archives, post categories etc. Which is the best way to share the same data on each of our controllers?

Iguess the most easy fix is to use the same `before_action`s on each controller, but this doesn't DRY up much our code, or maybe move all these into a parent class/cotrnoller that all controllers will inhert from, but is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Simple Solution:

- Normally, I just put these into `application_controller.rb` as a `before_action`.

**Example**

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
before_action :set_sidebar_resources
# ...

private

def set_sidebar_resources
  @sidebar_archives = Archive.all
  @sidebar_categories = Category.all
end
```

### Modular Solution:

- Simple solution above works great until you define more and more methods and other global controller logic into ApplicationController, and then the file becomes too big to manage. The following is a less conventional approach favouring more of manageability rather than simplicity.

**Example**

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
include WithSidebar
```

```
# app/controllers/concerns/with_sidebar.rb
module WithSidebar
  extend ActiveModel::Concern
  included do
    before_action :set_sidebar_resources

    private

    def set_sidebar_resources
      @sidebar_archives = Archive.all
      @sidebar_categories = Category.all
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, the simple solution is what I 'd probably do myself, but the manageable seems better and probably is much easier to manage when having lots of data

Comment: Yes, in big projects such as one I've been part of, we use concerns and basic includeable modules :)

Answer (score 1):

Rails controllers inherit from application controller.

ex.

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
```

You could add `before_actoion` to `ApplicationController` that pulls the data you want into `@variable` and then use that variable in other controllers.

Just don't over-do it and keep your controllers skinny :)